# More idiomatic way to handle simple file writing in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there anything you would change about the following function? I welcome any feedback on style, correctness, etc. Thank you for reading.

Some of my questions are:

1. Obviously, I catch the exception and convert it to a return value because I don't want to take down the application in case of an error. Would it be better to allow the exception to propagate up and handle it there (in the function that is coordinating the creation of the set of import files)?
2. Is there another, "better-in-general" way of writing to files?

   ```
   private static bool CreateImportFile(string path, string content)
   {
       try
       {
           using (var fileStreamWriter = File.CreateText(path))
           {
               fileStreamWriter.Write(content);
               fileStreamWriter.Close();
           }
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Failed to write import file due to IOException. " + e.Message);
           return false;
       }

       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: It's just about as idiomatic as it can be, just leave out the `Close()` call, it will be handled by the `using` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is more idiomatic but I think this style does not really add much benefit over calling `File.WriteAllText` directly. Consider what your client code will need to do to handle a single `bool` result with no other information as to why it failed.

```
private static bool CreateImportFile(string path, string content)
{
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, content);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to write import file due to IOException. " + e.Message);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Obviously my .NET knowledge is still pretty weak-- looks like my function is superfluous as WriteAllText is basically exactly what I need.

Comment: This is pretty good. I would write to stderr instead.